# Is Abel Ruffini's impossibility theory correct?

Tags: group-theory

If the Bring Jerrard Quintic is written this in this form
$$
x^5-(N^4+a_4 N^3+a_3 N^2+a_2 N+a_0/N)x+a_4 N^4+a_3 N^3+a_2 N^2+a_0=0\quad (1)
$$
Such that auxiliary quartic equation for the form is
$$
〖a_4 x〗^4+a_3 x^3+a_2 x^2-N^2 (a_4 N^2+a_3 N+a_2)=0 \quad (2)
$$
In this form the first root of the equation is $x_1=N$.

Why will it still not be possible to have a general solution of the general quintic in radical form? At least can any one prove that N is not a root of quintic 1 above?

Comment: Other solvable forms
Form 2 
x^5-(N^3+a_4 N^2+a_3 N+a_1/N+a_0/N^2 ) x^2+a_4 N^4+a_3 N^3+a_1 N+a_0=0 
In this case the auxiliary quartic equation is: 
a_4 x^4+a_3 x^3+a_2 x^2-N^2 (a_4 N^2+a_3 N+a_1/N)=0 
In this form the first root of the equation is x_1=N 
Form 3 
x^5-(N^2+a_4 N+a_2/N+a_1/N^2 +a_0/N^3 ) x^3+a_4 N^4+a_2 N^2+a_1 N+a_0=0 
In this case the auxiliary quartic equation is:
a_4 x^4+a_2 x^3+a_1 x-N^2 (a_4 N^2+a_2+a_1/N)=0  
In this form the first root of the equation is x_1=N

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the quintic you've written above can be factored as $$(x-N)(x^4+Nx^3+N^2x^2+N^3x-a_4N^3-a_3N^2-a_2N-a_0/N)$$ So the quintic you've given does indeed have a solution in radicals; one root is $N$ and the other four come from the quartic (which we know *does* have a solution in radicals). But Abel-Ruffini doesn't state that *no* quintics have a solution in radicals (else $x^5$ would be an easy counterexample!), only that it can't be done in general; this is a deep fact that's certainly not easy to see. A couple standard examples for polynomials that can't be solved by radicals are $x^5-x+1$ and $x^5+2x+2$.

Comment: the general quintic can also be factored into linear and quartic factors. This means that a general solution of of the general quintic is possible.So how can it be done in general? On how to factor a general quintic link to If the criteria of solving a quintic is its ability to be factored then the general quintic can also be factored.On how to factor a general quintic link here :http://dx.doi.org/10.7392/openaccess.2305042

Comment: The general quintic cannot be factored further as such over the rationals. $x^5+2x+2$ is irreducible over the rationals; it has no factors of smaller degree. You can further factor any polynomial into factors of at most degree two over the reals, but when people talk about a polynomial being solved by radicals, they usually mean to say that its roots are expressible in some function of the coefficients that is made by composing addition, multiplication, $n^{th}$ roots, etc; this isn't possible for the quintic.

Comment: A general quintic relation can be used to solve it over all rationals and irrationals is given by: 
a_4=-(N+a_3/N+a_2/N^2 +a_1/N^3 +a_0/N^4  ) where x_1=N . By choosing  a_3 ,a_2, a_1, a_0 and N a_4 is calculated, the polynomial the auxiliary quartic equations are  all generated in radical form. The coefficients of the auxiliary quartic equations are calculated as: b_3=-(a_3/N+a_2/N^2 +a_1/N^3 +a_0/N^4 )
 b_2=-(a_2/N+a_1/N^2 +a_0/N^3 ) ; b_1=-(a_1/N+a_0/N^2 ) ; b_0=-a_0/N
Task is impossible by Both Galois theory and Abel- Ruffini impossibility theorems

Comment: @Samuel:The general quintic formula proposed  generates the quintic auxiliary quartic equations, from a given root, rational or irrational and then generates the other four roots in radical form. If one begins by feeding an irrational root, then the quintic is unsolvable by Galois theorem but solvable by the formula. The formula can therefore generate different solutions in radical forms of quintics that are unsolvable by Galois   theory. Stating  from a selected value of a root N and four or less values of the coefficients, the polynomial is generated together with its roots in radical form

Comment: @Samuel, Mike’s quintics are of the general form x^5+px+q=0. For such quintics the relation between p, q and a root N (rational or irrational) is given by p=-(N^4+q/N) By choosing q and N (rational or irrational) a quintic is generated (which may or may not be solvable by the criteria of Galois theory), to root in radical form. The other roots are generated in radical form by the auxiliary quintic. In that sense Galois and Abel-Ruffini theorem are disproved. What do you think Mike?

Comment: @Samuel, In summary a relationship connecting symmetric group five and other lower order symmetric groups is:
s_5=N^5 (1-s_1/N-s_2/N^2 -s_3/N^3 -s_4/N^4 ) ;  N, is a root of the polynomial, real or complex, rational or irrational. The relationship suggests that there general relationship by which a general symmetric group s_5 can degenerate into lower order and solvable symmetric groups. A group s_n thus solvable in radicals if a general relationship can be found by which it can degenerate to symmetry groups with n≤4. The general quintic , by this argument is solvable by radicals.

Comment: @Samuel, In summary a relationship connecting symmetric group five and other lower order symmetric groups is:
s_5=N^5 (1-s_1/N-s_2/N^2 -s_3/N^3 -s_4/N^4 ) ;  N, is a root of the polynomial, real or complex, rational or irrational. The relationship suggests that there general relationship by which a general symmetric group s_5 can degenerate into lower order and solvable symmetric groups. A group s_n thus solvable in radicals if a general relationship can be found by which it can degenerate to symmetry groups with n≤4. The general quintic , by this argument is solvable by radicals.

Comment: @SamuelBonayaBuya what you have triwwtn there with $S_5$ does not make any sense at all. And in everything you have written, you seem to be assuming that $N$ can be found in terms of radicals, which there is no good reason why should be the case.

Comment: I post this answer of user [Samuel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/466430/samuel) who is not allowed to post comments, because I think his answer will be deleted soon: 
https://getpocket.com/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rroij.com%2Fopen-access%2Fthe-bringjerrard-quintic-equation-its-algebraic-solution-byconversion-to-solvable-factorized-form-.pdf&formCheck=abd1a95dfcd8022075bddaebecbd78a8 Read here algebraic solution of quintic equations